# Eclipse refactor renaming without saving all files

Tags: eclipse, refactoring, renaming

I'm currently using Eclipse to work on a PHP project. I commonly need to rename files but have others open that have changed that i'm not quite ready to save. I go to rename a file and a refactoring window pops up to save all documents. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Simple renaming is available on 'Navigator'(Window->Show View->Navigator) or 'Project Explorer'(Window->Show View->Other->General/Project Explorer).
(it seems that there is no workaround on PHP Explorer)